# Populate Spinner Data from sqliteDB in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, kotlin, spinner

I Have a local database (Sqlite) that im trying to get all the data from one column and populate that into a Spinner inside a fragment.  I'm trying to get the data from db and insert them to an array so it will be easy, Can you guys help me with this? A code sample will be much helpful. I've somehow done this but it's not showing the String value but instead show the reference value like "com.example.newsreader.model.PreferenceM@366732f"... I dunno how to convert this into a readable String.

**Relevant Code Snippet**

```
private fun preferencesInit(){
    //load the preferences list
    val prefList =   dbHandler.getAllPrefernces(activity!!.applicationContext)
    val spinner = spinner_preferences

    val preferences = prefList.toTypedArray()//arrayOfNulls<String>(prefList.size)
//        prefList.toArray()

    val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(activity!!.applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, preferences)
    spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
//        spinner.setOnClickListener {
            spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>,
                    view: View,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    if (preferences.isEmpty() || preferences.size == 0){
                        //do nothing
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(
                            activity!!.applicationContext,"preference selected : " +  preferences[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        checkQueryText(preferences[position].toString())
                    }
                }
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                    // Code to perform some action when nothing is selected
                    queryTopHeadlines()
                }
            }
//            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the toString method in the model class that you are trying to put in your adapter.

In your com.example.newsreader.model.PreferenceM, do the following:

```
override fun toString(): String{
  return <the field you want to put in your adapter>
}
```